# How to set up email notification for identify the last commit user and send codepipline status

Tags: amazon-sns, aws-codepipeline

I am working on AWS Codepipeline, How to set up e-mail notifications for developer did last commit and build was failed. Now identify the user and send automatic email for the developer along with manager. Can anyone please help on this

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use notification rules to notify users of important changes, such as when a pipeline starts execution. Notification rules specify both the events and the Amazon SNS topic that is used to send notifications. On the SNS topic, a subscription could be a User/Manager email address. Details here: [0]

Currently the notification message that is sent in case of, for example, pipeline success, does not include the Commit id or the Committer information [1].

As a work-around I suggest to implement additional stages within the pipeline that would Invoke a Lambda Function. The Lambda Function can then be programmed to publish the detailed event message [2] to the SNS using AWS SDKs. Detailed instructions for this set-up are documented at [3].

References:

[0] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/notification-rule-create.html

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html#codepipeline_event_type

[2] Example JSON Event  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-invoke-lambda-function.html#actions-invoke-lambda-function-json-event-example

[3] Invoke an AWS Lambda Function in a Pipeline in AWS CodePipeline  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-invoke-lambda-function.html